# Sending data in django without creating forms

Tags: django

There is already a subscribe field in my html page.
I don't want to create another django form.
how can I send data from here?

```
<div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon fh5co_footer_text_box" id="basic-addon1"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control fh5co_footer_text_box" placeholder="Enter your email..." aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
                <a href="#" class="input-group-addon fh5co_footer_subcribe" id="basic-addon12"> <i class="fa fa-paper-plane-o"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Subscribe</a>

            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put your code inside `form` tags that points to your django view:

```
<form action="url_of_your_view" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
</form>
```

and you can get the data in your view using `request.POST` but don't forget the `{% csrf_token %}` in your form.